# Getting an error saying that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Tags: reactjs, arrays, mongodb

```
Post.jsx:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Post (Post.jsx:22:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:1)
```

Getting the following error while trying to display the posts

**Posts.jsx**

```
const Posts =  () => {
  const posts =  useSelector((state)=> (state.posts))
  console.log(posts.length)
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    !posts.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
      <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
        {posts?.map((post) => (
          <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
            <Post post={post}  />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    )
  );
}
```

**src/actions/posts.js**

```
export const getPosts = () => async(dispatch) =>{
    try {
        const  {data}  = await api.fetchPost()
        console.log([data]);
        dispatch({type:'FETCH_ALL', payload:[data]})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}
```

**src/reducers/posts.js**

```
export default (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return [...posts, action.payload];
    
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}
```

The code is being followed from [Js Mastery's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsUzmlZfYNg&t=5542s)

According to me this may be because of changed version as the video was published 2 years ago and the data is being fetched from mongo db

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a field from an object that does not exist. So, when you want to read a specific field from an object, use the question mark (?) like this:

```
<Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
  {posts?.map((post, index) => (
     <Grid key={post?._id || index} item xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
         <Post post={post}  />
      </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but still getting the same error